# Why is object copy constructed and destructed twice?

Tags: c++, destructor, copy-constructor, copy-elision

*Why does an "extra" pair of copy constructor and destruction occur in code below?*

It happens when the constructor of Dingledong takes an STL container as an argument (I've tried std::vector and std::list). It may happen for other things? It doesn't happen if the constructor takes a pointer instead. It also doesn't happen if I allocate ding on heap instead( Dingledong* ding = new Dingledong(v) ).

```
#include <list>
#include <iostream>

class Dingledong{
public:
    Dingledong(std::list<int> numbers)
    {
        std::cout << "construction\n";
        numbers_ = numbers;
    }
    Dingledong(Dingledong const& other)
    {
        std::cout << "COPY construction\n";
    }
    ~Dingledong()
    {
        std::cout << "destructed\n";
        // I would do some cleanup here.. unsubscribe from events, whatever..
        // but the destructor is called sooner than I would expect and thus
        // the cleanup is done prematurely.
    }
    std::list<int> numbers_;
};

void diller()
{
    std::cout << "diller started.. " << std::endl;
    std::list<int> v = std::list<int>(34);
    // Having an STL container as parameter in constructor causes Dingledong's copy constructor to 
    // be used to create a temporary Dingledong which is immediately destructed again. Why?
    Dingledong ding = Dingledong(v);
    std::cout << "Has ding been destructed?\n";
}

int main()
{
    diller();
    system("pause");
}
```

**Output:**

```
diller started...
construction
COPY construction     // I didn't expect this to happen
destructed            // I didn't expect this to happen
Has ding been destructed?
destructed
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What compiler are you using? I would have expected that copy to be elided. Also, what makes you think it is related to "STL" containers?

Comment: My compiler is the one that came with Visual Studio 2013.
The STL container thing is merely the only pattern that I've found so far. I would expect it to happen for other things.

Comment: Are you compiling with optimizations turned off? I'd be very surprised if the copy is not being elided in *Release* mode.

Comment: Well, you should check that before making such claims and adding all kinds of potentially irrelevant information and tags.

Comment: MSVC (up until 2015, I think) did not perform copy elision for Debug builds

Comment: Was compiling release build with optimizations on.

Comment: Now compile a release version and see the copy magically disappear.

Comment: @LokiAstari I can confirm that a release build in VS2013 still has the same behaviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code:

```
Dingledong ding = Dingledong(v);
```

means:

1. Create temporary object of type `Dingledong`, initialized with `v`
2. Create object `ding`, initialized with the temporary object.

The copy-constructor comes in step 2 here. If you do not want a copy, don't write code that specifies a copy. For example:

```
Dingledong ding(v);   // no copy
```

Compilers may implement a feature called *copy elision* where this temporary object is optimized out (even though the copy-constructor has a side-effect), but they don't have to and in this case there is no reason to rely on that.

---

You could improve your code by adding a move-constructor, in which case (if the compiler does not perform copy elision) the operation would be a move instead of a copy, which is less expensive.

There are also a wasted copy in your constructor  (`numbers` is copied from `v`, and then `numbers_` is copied from `numbers`, and also `numbers_` is initialized and then assigned, instead of just being initialized). This would be a much better constructor:

```
Dingledong(std::list<int> numbers): numbers_( std::move(numbers) )
{
    std::cout << "construction\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That explains it. I never realized that the two were not equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Your Output:

```
diller started...
construction                //(1)
COPY construction           //(2)
destructed                  //(3)
Has ding been destructed?
destructed                  //(4)
```

And the relevant bit of code:

```
Dingledong ding = Dingledong(v);
```

Dingledong(v) creates a temporary object. (1) is printed.

You assign this temp object to ding (actually, this is syntactic sugar to call a copy constructor). (2) is printed.

Once the statement is completed, the temp object is destroyed. (3) is printed.
Your code runs, and once ding goes out of scope it's destroyed, (4) is printed.